# CREATE JSON SWIFTYJSON

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, swifty-json

I am trying to create a json like this

```
[
 {"key": "value"},
 {"key": "value"},
 {"key": "value"}
]
```

this is my code

```
var array: JSON = []
    for i in (0..<obj.count){
        array = [
            "user": obj[i].name!,
            "apikey": obj[i].key!
        ]
    }
```

But when I try to print, only I get with the first item,
How can I resolve that

Comment: use array.append ...

Comment: It does not have append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Codable`. Since Swift 4 `SwiftyJSON` became obsolete

```
struct Object : Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name  = "user", key = "apikey" }
    let name, key : String
}

let obj = [Object(name: "Foo", key: "API123"), Object(name: "Bar", key: "API456")]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(obj)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: How can I populate with for loop?

Comment: The funny thing is you don't need a loop, just encode your `obj` array.

Comment: wat happen if i had 20 items?, what type is var obj?

Comment: 20 or 100 is irrelevant. The same type as your `obj` array. You have adopt `Encodable` in your struct and add the `CodingKeys`

Comment: Finally I understand your code and is the correct answer thaaaaaaaanks